# Insert a picture in an Android Application

Tags: android

I want to insert a picture from my filesystem to a new Android Project.
What code do I have to write and especially where?
That means in **src/package/main.java** and or in **res/layout/activity_main.xml**???

Answer (score 0):

Put it into res/drawable.

Anyway, go for this piece of documentation. It is worth the time: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thanks You! But there is no code how I can insert the picture into my Graphical Layout.